# wget jpg from url list keeping same structure

Tags: bash, sh, wget, cycle, mkdir

I have a 9000 urls list to scrap into a file.txt keeping same dir structure as writed in the url list.

Each url is composed by http://domain.com/$dir/$sub1/$ID/img_$ID.jpg where $dir and $sub1 are integer numbers from 0 to 9

I tried running

```
wget -i file.txt
```

but it takes any img_$ID.jpg in the same local dir where i'm, so i get any file in root loosing the $dir/%sub1/$ID folders structure.

I thought have to write a script which does

```
mkdir -p $dir/$sub1/$ID
wget -P $dir/$ #Correcting a typo in the message i left the full path pending, it was the same as previous mkdir command => "wget -P $dir/$sub1/$ID"
```

for each line in file.txt, but i have no idea on where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think simple shell loop with a bit of string processing should work for you:

```
while read line; do
  line2=${line%/*}     # removing filename
  line3=${line2#*//}   # removing "http://"
  path=${line3#*/}     # removing "domain.com/"
  mkdir -p $path
  wget -P$path $line
done <file.txt
```

(SO's editor mis-interprets `#` in the expression and colors the rest of the string as comment - don't mind it. The actual comments are on the very right.)

Notice that `wget` command is not as you described (`wget -P $dir/$`), but rather the one that seems more correct (`wget -P $dir/$sub1/$ID`). If you insist on your version, please clarify what do you mean by terminal `$`.

Also, for the purpose of debugging you might wanna verify the processing before you run the actual script (that copies the files) - you may do something like that:

```
while read line; do
  echo $line
  line2=${line%/*}     # removing filename
  echo $line2
  line3=${line2#*//}   # removing "http://"
  echo $line3
  path=${line3#*/}     # removing "domain.com/"
  echo $path
done <file.txt
```

You'll see all string processing steps and will make sure the resulting path is correct.